# Copy a range of cells, defined on execution, to an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy, range

I am trying to copy a range of cells from a range of rows from two workbooks. This information is used to do a comparison of the contents of both workbooks rows by ID.

The first solution I tried involved cell by cell "binary" comparison. This works for worksheets with few rows:

```
For i = 2 To LastSheetRow
    Set FoundCell = Workbooks(WorkbookA).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Range("A:A").Find(What:=Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(i, 1).Value)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then

        aCellValues(0) = 1
        Workbooks(UserWorkbook).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(i, LastSheetColumn + 1).Value = FoundCell.Row
        For j = 2 To LastSheetColumn
            Select Case Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(i, j).Value
            Case Is = Workbooks(WorkbookA).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(FoundCell.Row, j).Value
                aCellValues(j - 1) = 1

            Case Else
                aCellValues(j - 1) = 0
            End Select
        Next j
    Else
    End If
Next i
```

I would like to store the contents of one row of each of the two workbooks on one array to do the comparison, as I believe it's a faster solution.

After defining the range to do the comparison I encountered the following error when copying the cells into an array:

> Subindex out of interval (Error 9)

This generates the error:

```
Dim aWorkbookBInfo() As Variant, aWorkbookAInfo() As Variant, rngWorkbookBToCompare As Range, rngWorkbookAToCompare As Range
Dim SumToCheck As Integer, FoundCell As Range, aCellValues() As Integer   
ReDim aCellValues(LastSheetColumn - 1)
ReDim aWorkbookBInfo(LastSheetColumn - 1)
ReDim aWorkbookAInfo(LastSheetColumn - 1)
For i = 2 To LastSheetRow
    Set FoundCell = Workbooks(WorkbookA).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Range("A:A").Find(What:=Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(i, 1).Value)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then        
        aCellValues(0) = 1
        Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(i, LastSheetColumn + 1).Value = FoundCell.Row
        With Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray)
            Set rngWorkbookBToCompare = Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, LastSheetColumn))
        End With
        With Workbooks(WorkbookA).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray)
            Set rngWorkbookAToCompare = Range(Cells(FoundCell.Row, 2), Cells(FoundCell.Row, LastSheetColumn))
        End With
        aWorkbookBInfo = rngWorkbookBToCompare
        aWorkbookAInfo = rngWorkbookAToCompare
        For j = 1 To LastSheetColumn - 1
            If aWorkbookBInfo(j).Value = aWorkbookAInfo(j).Value Then                
                aCellValues(j) = 1                
            Else
                aCellValues(j) = 0
            End If
        Next j
    Else
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Complete Revision:**

The range array assignment produces a two-dimensional array in these lines:

```
aWorkbookBInfo = rngWorkbookBToCompare
aWorkbookAInfo = rngWorkbookAToCompare
```

This happens regardless of how you defined and dimensioned them at the beginning of your code. Since they are a two-dimensional array, they must be addressed as `aWorkbookBInfo(a, b)` where `a` is a row and `b` is a column.

Unlike Ranges, where it is okay to reference the first cell in any range, you must fully address an array before attempting to reference the array item. So, while `rngWorkbookBToCompare(j).Value` works, `aWorkbookBInfo(j).Value` does not. Furthermore, *Value* is not necessarily a property of whatever object Excel puts in the array. If you want the first cell of column `j`, try adding the row and leaving off the reference to the *Value* property as in: `aWorkbookBInfo(1, j)`.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I see I didn't add the information about how I declared them in the original post. I'll add it now.

Comment: I tried adding "set" at the beginning of both lines and it gives the following compilation error: “Can't assign to array”.

Comment: I have completely revised my answer.

Comment: After applying the changes you proposed, it seems to work now. Also, good explanation of the reasons. Thanks!

Comment: I realized that with large datasets, at some point, when reading the arrays they return null values or some of the names of both workbooks' sheets instead of the cell values. I believe it is related to how I have written the "with" to assign the value of the ranges "rngWorkbookBToCompare" and "rngWorkbookAToCompare". I'm not quite sure if I'm missing any element in the reference that could be causing the error ; or if it's better to use an alternative way to define the range.

Comment: Hi. Three things: 1.) It is customary to [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer resolves your question. 2.) Using comments on an old question is not the best way to get an answer. That only notifies the original people involved in your question. It is best to create a new question. That serves both you and the community better. 3.) Your `With` statement in your code is not being used. If `Range` and `Cells` are not dereferenced with the dot, they use the active workbook.