# Assign a group of cells, defined on execution, to a range

Tags: excel, vba, range, row

I am trying to assign a group of cells from two rows of two workbooks to two ranges. This information is used to do a [comparison of the contents of both workbooks rows by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036852/copy-a-range-of-cells-defined-on-execution-to-an-array-excel-vba).

I tried using "with" statements.

```
Dim aWorkbookBInfo() As Variant, aWorkbookAInfo() As Variant, rngWorkbookBToCompare As Range, rngWorkbookAToCompare As Range
Dim SumToCheck As Integer, FoundCell As Range, aCellValues() As Integer
ReDim aCellValues(LastSheetColumn - 1)
ReDim aWorkbookBInfo(LastSheetColumn - 1)
ReDim aWorkbookAInfo(LastSheetColumn - 1)
For i = 2 To LastSheetRow
    Set FoundCell = Workbooks(WorkbookA).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Range("A:A").Find(What:=Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(i, 1).Value)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        aCellValues(0) = 1
        Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray).Cells(i, LastSheetColumn + 1).Value = FoundCell.Row
        With Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray)
            Set rngWorkbookBToCompare = Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, LastSheetColumn))
        End With
        With Workbooks(WorkbookA).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray)
            Set rngWorkbookAToCompare = Range(Cells(FoundCell.Row, 2), Cells(FoundCell.Row, LastSheetColumn))
        End With
        aWorkbookBInfo = rngWorkbookBToCompare
        aWorkbookAInfo = rngWorkbookAToCompare
        For j = 1 To LastSheetColumn - 1
            If aWorkbookBInfo(1, j) = aWorkbookAInfo(1, j) Then
                aCellValues(j) = 1 
            Else
                aCellValues(j) = 0
            End If
        Next j
    Else
    End If
Next i
```

I would like to store the contents of the groups of cells from both workbooks without activating them, as I believe the process would be faster.

What I tried gets only the information of the active workbook instead of both workbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a period `.` before `Range` or `Cells` references to fully qualify the `Worksheet` within the `With...End With` block.

```
With Workbooks(WorkbookB).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray)
    Set rngWorkbookBToCompare = .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, LastSheetColumn))
End With
```

And again:

```
With Workbooks(WorkbookA).Sheets(SheetNameFromArray)
    Set rngWorkbookAToCompare = .Range(.Cells(FoundCell.Row, 2), .Cells(FoundCell.Row, LastSheetColumn))
End With
```

Without the period, the `With...End With` has no effect. The `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveWorkbook` are implied since the `Range` and `Cells` calls are not fully qualified.